# Call in 3G modem Python, PyAudio

Tags: python, call, pyaudio

I have two python scripts. The first calls with At Commands, and second receives audio and sends it to the computer microphone. The problem is that when I send the audio the modem resets or is very slow to listen.

First (docall.py)

```
import serial

se = serial.Serial()
se.port = 5
se.baudrate = 9600 # may be different
se.timeout = 0.5

a=1
se.open()
cont=0
while (a==1):
 if not se.isOpen():
  se.open()
 if cont == 1:
  se.write('AT+CHUP;\r\n')
  se.write('ATD*264;\r\n')
 if cont == 2:
  se.write('AT^DDSETEX?;\r\n')
 if cont == 3:
  se.write('AT^DDSETEX=2;\r\n')

 line = se.read(1024)
 print (line)
 cont=cont+1

se.close()
```

---

Second (audio.py)

```
import serial
import pyaudio
import wave
import time

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 8000
RECORD_SECONDS = 10
WIDTH = 2

pe = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream= pe.open(format=pe.get_format_from_width(WIDTH),
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                output=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

mic= pe.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                channels=1,
                rate=8000,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=128)

se = serial.Serial()
se.port = 3
se.baudrate = 9600 # may be different
se.timeout = 0.5
se.open()
se.writeTimeout = 0

streaming = []
frames = []
while True:
 re= se.read(CHUNK)
 stream.write(re)
 se.write(mic.read(612))
```

Comment: The code itself sounds fine, although the state machine construction in the first step is very awkward and there are much easier ways to do it in Python. How do you know this is a Python problem as opposed to a hardware problem... ?

Comment: because when i test with a modem compiled software the call listen fine.

Comment: So you replace `audio.py` with some other program, and leave `docall.py` alone, and it works fine? If so, then you've at least narrowed down the problem to `audio.py`. Sounds like you need to verify that `audio.py` does the exact same thing as the compiled program (written in C?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the frame buffer 160 in order to match the device rate. I'm using the pa device callback in order to write and read from the device, the key number is 320 frame per buffer.

```
device = Serial('/dev/tty.HUAWEIMobile-Diag', timeout=None,  writeTimeout=0)

time.sleep(0.1) #this sleep needed for device buffer clean
device.flush()
device.flushInput()
device.flushOutput()

uni_stream = pe.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                     channels=1,
                     rate=8000,
                     input=True,
                     output=True,
                     frames_per_buffer=160, stream_callback=uni_callback)

def uni_callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    data = device.read(320)
    device.write(in_data)

    return (data, pyaudio.paContinue)
```